# sending several variables using ajax (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing

I am trying to send 2 variables in a JQuery Ajax call, but for some reason, both variables end up bundled in the first one:

```
function getNextQuestion(answer, queryType)
{    
    $.ajax
    ({
        async: false,
        url: 'handlers/question_hdlr.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "answer="+ answer +"&queryType=" + queryType,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
           ...
        },error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
           alert ("error: "+textStatus);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

When I run it in the debugger, I get only one variable:

`$_POST["answer"]`, containing `"answerqueryTypequeryType"`

`$_POST["queryType"]` does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that there is nothing wrong in the code in the question, the only problem was that the Javascript file cached by the browser contained a typo and even though the problem was fixed on the working copy, the browser was never actually running it.

The solution was to add the date & time to the script url as a parameter to prevent the browser from using the cached version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $pathRoot ?>js/commline.js?<?= date(U);?>" />
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to manually serialize your data.  Just pass an object and jQuery will serialize it for you.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: { answer: answer, queryType: queryType }
});
```

Also, **never** issue AJAX requests with `async:false`.  There's never a valid reason to use a synchronous XHR request.

Comment: Sorry, I just found out what the problem was. Both codes work, but my browser was still using a cached copy of a previous version of the js file which had a typo in it.

Comment: What's the issue with async:false? The workflow involves going from one question to the next, nothing else. I don't want the user to go off and do anything else on the site until the next question is loaded. Isn't that what async:false does?

Comment: @Sylverdrag: Synchronous XHR *freezes the entire browser UI*, which is embarrassingly bad UX.  See [this relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336382/how-to-invoke-a-please-wait-window-only-if-ajax-takes-more-than-x-milliseconds/7337091#7337091).

Comment: Outch, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out to me. It's actually a serious weakness if anyone can crash the browser just by asking resources over and over again