# Perform asynchronous call before calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have a function, authenticate() that uses $post() to retrieve a session key from my server. I believe $post is an asynchronous call. Whenever I perform any action in my script, I want to ensure that I have a sessionKey, and if I do not have a sessionKey I want to authenticate(). My problem is how do I run performTask() after I have called authenicate()?

```
function foo() {
    if (sessionKey) {
        performTask();
    } else {
        authenciate();
        performTask();
    }
}

function authenticate() {       
    $.post(url, function(data) {
        sessionKey = data.sessionKey;
    });
}
```

EDIT: I also do not want to put in authenticate()'s callback function performTask() as authenticate() will be called from several different functions.

Comment: As a callback function on post' success

Comment: Check the simplified update. You can make the caller just add a small bit to it for every authenticated call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a callback to the authenticate method.  If authenticate is called from 20 different places, you can pass in 20 different callback methods.

```
function foo() {
    if (sessionKey) {
        performTask();
    } else {
        authenciate(function() {
           performTask();
        });
    }
}

function authenticate(callback) {       
    $.post(url, function(data) {
        sessionKey = data.sessionKey;
        if (callback) callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: @icu222much: This answer is on the right track, but it's missing one important piece that @minitech's answer has -- checking that a callback was passed to `authenticate` before trying to invoke it.  (`if (callback) callback();`)  Otherwise, simply calling `authenticate();` (without a callback) will throw a `ReferenceError` .  I've taken the liberty of adding the appropriate check.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the callback to `authenticate()` itself using jQuery's Promise interface (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)):

```
function authenticate(callback) {
    var rq = $.post(url, function(data) {
        sessionKey = data.sessionKey;
    });

    if(callback) {
        rq.success(callback);
    }
}
```

Now just call `authenticate(performTask)`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's AJAX calls have callback functions (success and error). You can pass in the after-authentication action as the callback to do it after authentication has completed.

Alternately, you can set am option to make the calls synchronous.

Sorry for not linking to the documentation; I'm posting from my phone. Just google "jquery.ajax" to find the documentation.

**EDIT:**As a response to your edit, you could give your authenticate method a parameter to use as a callback function if you want to change what happens after the call (or do nothing) on a case-by- case basis.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

It has an example of doing AJAX synchronously. Basically you pass an `async:false` param, and might require using the `ajax()` method instead of the `post()` shortcut to it.

**Update:**

Another thing you can do is wrap the whole thing in a function like:

```
function foo() {
    authenciate(function() {
       performTask();
    });
}

function authenticate(callback) {     

    if (!callback) { return; }

    if (sessionKey) {
        callback();
    } else {
        $.post(url, function(data) {
            sessionKey = data.sessionKey;
            callback();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: -1; [**never** use synchronous AJAX calls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7337091/201952).