# Parsing Complex JSON Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am able to parse JSON that returns simple data, with JSON.parse but I am having trouble with data that returns objects, dates, strings, etc..

```
var theData=JSON.parse(theData);
```

Something like this JSON.parse returns [Object] object back with no data at all (I can see the data is being successfully returned because it returns all the data as a string if I have JSON.parse turned off).

```
{
"AppName": "TheName",
"AppUrl": "https:\/\/app\/icons\/unknown.png",
"aGUID": "45c055d2-2edc-d4444"."DateCreated": "8\/23\/2012 11:04AM", {
    "ID": "yser123",
    Name ":" User "}
    }
```

What is the best way to go about parsing this data in javascript(I am not able to use jquery)?

Note: I had wrote the JSON assume its valid

Here is the code I am using to retreive the data..

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("POST", "ClientService.svc/REST/GetDetail", false);
xhReq.send(null);
var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
alert(serverResponse);
return serverResponse;
```

Comment: That particular string you posted is invalid JSON.  There's a missing `"` character towards the end. Otherwise `JSON.parse()` will handle anything (that's valid JSON).

Comment: Why are you scaping "/"?

Comment: @david thats the way the its being returned

Comment: Yes it needs to be valid JSON.Here's a good resource for checking if your JSON is valid: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @davidbuzatto because the JSON spec requires it?

Comment: The JSON is valid, I wrote the JSON by hand, assume its valid, the JSON does come with the scaping shown though is that screwing it up somehow?

Comment: @NickLaMarca the JSON you've written here is definitely _not_ valid.

Comment: I cant show the actual data its sensitive so I had wrote a sample of what it looks like. The data is returned with scaping though

Comment: @NickLaMarca specifically you've got a '.' instead of a ',' in front of the `DateCreated` field and there's no key for the final `{"ID":"yser123",Name":"User"}` value.

Comment: You make it difficult for people to help you if you don't post accurate information. The `JSON.parse()` mechanism will parse any sort of JSON structure, regardless of how complicated it is, up to the point that it starts running out of memory.  Your sample JSON is definitely not too big. You should of course be checking for errors in the browser console.

Comment: @NickLaMarca is that object ({"AppName".......}) the result of JSON.parse(theData)?

Comment: no thats the result of responseText. JSON.parse returns [Object] object

Comment: Is the scaping seen above being looked at as invalid? Because the crappy scaping is being returned

Comment: The escaping of the forward-slashes is actually required, so that's OK.  You can take an actual sample of your JSON to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) and see if it's valid.

Comment: @Alnitak: Hi! I never noticed that / should be escaped in JSON, since the JSON parsers seems to not complain about that. Do you know why?

Comment: @NickLaMarca: Nick, "/" really needs to be escaped according to the spec (http://json.org/), but it seems that the parsers don't complain about that (escape or not escape). I already updated my answer to scape "/".

Comment: @davidbuzatto I don't know why - RFC 4627 itself fails to escape some forward-slashes in its examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, [**don't use synchronous XHR**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7337091/201952).  Rewrite your JavaScript to be asynchronous.

```
function getDetail(cb) {
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("POST", "ClientService.svc/REST/GetDetail", true);
    xhReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhReq.readyState == 4) cb(xhReq.responseText);
    }
    xhReq.send(null);
}

// to call:

getDetail(function(data) {
    JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Second, your problem is not that JSON is being parsed incorrectly.  It's your debugging call to `alert`.  When you pass the `serverResponse` **object**, `alert` coerces the object into a string by calling the object's `toString` method, which simply returns `'[object Object]'`.

Try `console.log`.  Objects can be inspected in the console.

Comment: Wow well that certainly cut through a lot of noise :-)

Comment: why cant I use synchronous XHR?

Comment: @NickLaMarca: As a rule, synchronous XHR is a major no-no.  There's detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2011/08/03/why-you-should-use-xmlhttprequest-asynchronously.aspx) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests), but most importantly, [sync XHR is being phased out](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs).

Answer (score 1):

It actually sounds like this is working. If you call some thing like this:

```
alert(JSON.parse(serverResponse))
```

It will display [object Object] which is correct. If you call

```
alert(JSON.parse(serverResponse).appName)
```

You should see the appName. If you are not seeing "SyntaxError"s being thrown, JSON.parse() is working

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is wrong and the data needs to be a string.

So, this will work (I broke the lines to improve readability):

```
var data = "{" + 
    "    \"AppName\": \"TheName\", " + 
    "    \"AppUrl\": \"https:\/\/app\/icons\/unknown.png\", " + 
    "    \"aGUID\": \"45c055d2-2edc-d4444\", " + 
    "    \"DateCreated\": \"8\/23\/2012 11:04AM\", " +
    "    \"foo\": { " + 
    "        \"ID\": \"yser123\", " + 
    "        \"Name\":\"User\"" + 
    "    }" + 
    "}";
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert( obj.AppName );
```

Of course, if you use simple quotes as string delimiter, the code would be:

```
var data = '{' + 
    '    "AppName": "TheName", ' + 
    '    "AppUrl": "https:\/\/app\/icons\/unknown.png", ' + 
    '    "aGUID": "45c055d2-2edc-d4444", ' + 
    '    "DateCreated": "8\/23\/2012 11:04AM", ' +
    '    "foo": { ' + 
    '        "ID": "yser123", ' + 
    '        "Name":"User"' + 
    '    }' + 
    '}';
```

This **not works**:

```
var data = "{" + 
    "    'AppName': 'TheName', " + 
    "    'AppUrl': 'https:\/\/app\/icons\/unknown.png', " + 
    "    'aGUID': '45c055d2-2edc-d4444', " + 
    "    'DateCreated': '8\/23\/2012 11:04AM', " +
    "    'foo': { " + 
    "        'ID': 'yser123', " + 
    "        'Name': 'User'" + 
    "    }" + 
    "}";
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pmdm/1/

Comment: why escape the double quotes when you could just have enclosed it in _single_ quotes...?

Comment: The JSON I have is created by C# from an actual .Net object I dont have control of the created JSON. The sample JSON I put in the question maybe invalid (missing quotes maybe) cause I hand wrote it for sample purposes. Is it possible .Net maybe screwing up the JSON returned?

Comment: Forward slashes should be quoted, though I agree that it seems unnecessary.  I think `JSON.parse()` won't insist on it but it's definitely valid.

Comment: @NickLaMarca, seems odd to me. And what .NET lib are you using? I always had to use JSON.Net, but there are some integrated options.

Could you paste output of the .Net side?

Comment: @Pointy: Hi! Thanks for the advice. I never noticed that :S, but as you said the parsers don't complain about that. I updated my answer to escape "/".