# Any alternative to synchronous XHR?

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest

I'm interfacing with a third party code (Chrome extension runtime, but it's not relevant to the problem itself). The code blocks until my function returns, which is desired behaviour. To give a meaningful output, my function needs to know the result of XHR. In code terms, it's laid out like this:

```
function() {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', false);
        xhr.send(null);
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            return jsonResponse['neededData'];
        } else {
            console.error('API response invalid.');
        };
    };
```

To me this is one of those use cases that fit the synchronous XHR. Unfortunately, [synchronous XHR is being deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method) and wanting to write future-proof code, I'm struggling to find an alternative. I did my research, but none of the options found on internet or SO satisfy my constraints:

- Fetch - asynchronous
- Wrapping synchronous XHR in worker thread - asynchronous
- [Rewriting to asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12680586/388636) - I have no control over the code I'm interfacing with.

Are there any other options?

Comment: if the code you are "interfacing" with requires synchronous responses, then you need to give synchronous responses - as nothing can turn asynchronous responses into synchronous responses - no such magic exists :p when you say `none of the options found` ... you mean you've found absolutely nothing, correct, because it's not like the magic exists, but it's not quite right?

Comment: I don't think blocking until the request comes back should be considered desirable. Better to embrace Javascript's asynchronicity and use `fetch` (and `await` when you want code to look flatter)

Comment: Nope, that's it. Either synchronous, with all its problems, or asynchronous, meaning your function can't know the answer. There's no third option.

Comment: @JaromandaX The point is that XHR is going to prevent me from doing so.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, but did you even read the question? I have no problem with asynchronous code, but I'm constrained by a third party code that provides no alternative.

Comment: Sure, but the point is that you have no control over the unnamed code you're interfacing with - the problem is with that code, not yours - the other problem MAY be is that you can't figure out how to interface with that unnamed code - but since that unnamed code is unnamed, then there's nothing we can do to help you interface with that unnamed code in an asynchronous manner

Comment: @Sidney Just to clarify, you did read the question and know that asynchronous handling of response isn't an option here?

Comment: @Sidney Sorry, but you either don't bother with reading my question or don't understand it: 3rd party code doesn't have synchronous HTTP, it waits for my function to complete before taking an action. This particular library has no alternative - Chrome extension runtime cannot be swapped for another.

Comment: I apologize, I did not understand your question. I see you are interface with a chrome.* API. Which one?

Comment: "it waits for my function to complete" - how? please show in the question an example of this

Comment: @Sidney `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` blocking.
@JaromandaX An example of how it waits for my function to complete? How do I provide this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm interfacing with a third party code (Chrome extension runtime, but it's not relevant to the problem itself)

Actually, I think the Chrome's runtime is very relevant here. Why? Well, Firefox has solved this! A Firefox extension can return a Promise and still modify request headers. [MDN docs for `webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders).

Yeah, this is confusing behavior on Chrome's part. It's been asked before: [BrowserExtension webRequest.onBeforeRequest return promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47910732/7486612)

For now, I think you're forced to keep the XHR synchronous. But if you want to be a little fancy, you can try using the async Promise API, and fallback to synchronous when running in Chrome.

I would view this as Chrome's fault, not your code. Chrome's extension API continues to be strange, like using `chrome.runtime.lastError` for reporting errors. Firefox, and the Web Extension spec, uses Promises. There are polyfills you can use in Chrome for access to some of the Promise-based APIs, but unfortunately this particular API cannot be polyfilled.

Comment: My extension is not meant to be cross-browser. But if Firefox provides Promise support, there's at least some hope Chrome will follow suit. Thanks.